# Euclidean, Non-Euclidean and Analytical Geometry books

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

What are some good books to study Euclidean, Non-Euclidean and Analytical Geometry from High School to University?

Comment: See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2636825/looking-for-euclidean-and-non-euclidean-geometry-books-recommendations-first-y?rq=1) and others here.

Answer (score 1):

(i) E.A. Maxwell's book "The methods of plane geometry based on the use of general homogeneous coordinates"
(ii) E.A. Maxwell's book on 3-dimensional projective geometry with homogeneous coordinates
(iii) Patrick J. Ryan's book "Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometry:an analytic appproach"
(iv) Hans Schwerdtfeger's book "The geometry of complex numbers"

Comment: Thanks. Although I couldn't find Maxwell's books available.

Comment: @ Joãofodão Go to BookFinder on the internet and search for (i)  author:E.A. Maxwell title:The methods of plane geometry based on the use of general homogeneous coordinates and (ii) author:  E.A. Maxwell title: General homogeneous coordinates in space of three dimensions. You will get a list of new/used copies, available through Abebooks, amazon.co (u.k.) and biblio.co. The used books are reasonably priced and the description of their condition is almost always honest. It is really wortwhile going to some trouble to get Maxwell's books.